# c++ template class iterator function outside class - Member declaration not found

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, member

I'm getting a "Member declaration not found" error for the operator++() function.
could someone help me please? what am I doing wrong? thanks!

```
template<class P, class T>
class PriorityQueue<P, T>::Iterator {

//...

public:

//...

Iterator& operator++();

//...

}

template<typename P,typename T>
typename PriorityQueue<P,T>::Iterator& PriorityQueue<P,T>::Iterator::operator++() {

//...

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: `typename PriorityQueue<P,T>::Iterator&` If you want to avoid such horrible names, just use `auto PriorityQueue<P,T>::Iterator::operator++() -> Iterator&`

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/S9M6ms) (having added the missing `;`). Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: could someone please explain why this:
 
template<typename P,typename T>
typename PriorityQueue<P,T>::Iterator& PriorityQueue<P,T>::Iterator::operator++() {}

doesn't work?

Comment: So it works with `auto` but not as you have written it? Or does it not work either way?

Comment: yes, the ` auto ` works great. I'm trying to understand why the second option is wrong

Comment: Please follow Angew's advice and provide a *complete* example that we just can just run through our compilers to reproduce the problem.

Comment: http://ideone.com/jKKv6b

Comment: Adding to dyp's comment: ... and *just* the problem. The `jKKv6b` link reports a whole lot of errors. Are they all part of what you're asking about?

Comment: here's a lighter version: http://ideone.com/OtQyob
I'm only asking about line 59. the way it is now is OK. but when it's:
PriorityQueue<P,T>::Iterator& PriorityQueue<P,T>::Iterator::operator++()
it doesn't work

Comment: @maxyor6040 The "lighter" version has some problems with order of declaration: `PriorityQueueElement` needs to be declared before `PriorityQueue`, since the latter has a data member of the former. Fixing that and adding some missing `typename`, the original problem does not appear: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c49f9244f0845941